CI CD with mutiple namespaces
I'am working on CI CD pipeline for four namespaces because i choose to seperate my environments using namespaces but in the pipeline in the build stage where is docker build and docker push for the images i haven't find a solution to build and push just the images that have been changed .. i  try using only:changes to just build and push the images that have been change but still not a good solution  .. is there any solution or architecture that i can follow it to do my task
